# infopath 2007 field count

Tags: development, column, infopath

Is there a menu option in InfoPath 2007 that would give me the total number of fields?

The reason that I am doing this is because I have a form that I developed that cannot be uploaded to a SharePoint 2010 server do to being to large. I was told by my server admin that I should try and limit the form to around 300 fields. Before I go about doing that I wanted to know what the current number of fields are to see if it is even feasible as I may have over 600 fields currently.

It would also be helpful if someone knew of a way around the field limit.

For reference there are 34 fields that are promoted, 14 of which are dates the file size of the form is 170 KB.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a limit in number of fields within InfoPath, it is the promoting of those fields as columns in a list that is limited. See more information here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823555.

Comment: Only promote fields that would be needed for filtering/sorting or needed for workflows in that case.

Comment: I only have 34 fields that are promoted, 14 of which are dates. So I'm not sure why it cannot be updated the form is 170 KB I have never heard of a file size limit and if this form is exceeding it that would be way to small in my mind.

The real follow up question is then what do I tell the Server admin to get him to upload it right?

Comment: Once filled out, the form might be exceeding some of the server settings for data connection response and session state.  In 2007, those were located in Central Admin in Application Management.  I'm not entirely sure where they'd be located in 2010 yet, we're still on MOSS 2007.